# Clean-Installing Windows 10 on a Samsung SM951 SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-installation, asus-laptop, nvme

I want to install Windows 10 on a new SM951 SSD (NVMe).
When booting from my install medium *(Zalman VE300, USB-Drive-Emulator, Windows 10 x64 ISO)*
the setup does not show the drive in the list of available disks.

Starting a CMD *(Shift+f10)* and running *diskpart list disk* doesn't show the SSD aswell.

Is there a driver i need to reload for the setup to recognize the SSD,
or how can i make the setup find the SSD?

My machine is a Asus ROG G572 with currently 3 installed drives

- 1TB   HHD
- 256GB SSD (NVMe) (Stock OS drive)
- 512GB SSD (NVMe, SM951) (Should become my new OS drive)

**Edit:**

When booting from my current OS dirve, Windows does detect all 3 disks
and all 3 are working properly. The problem occurs only in the windows setup.

**Edit 2:**

All 3 drives are visible in the BIOS *(Both SSDs: Status: Non-RAID, Controller Type: NVMe, CtrlInterface: PCIe)*
Using the drivers from http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/downloads/software/Samsung_NVMExpress_Driver_rev11.zip did not work (The setup did not find any signed drivers)

Comment: was HDD disconnected or disabled in BIOS during SSD install?

Comment: @TonyStewart No all 3 devices (including the HDD) were connected and enabled... is this a problem?

Comment: probably.  I think so

Comment: ok i diconnect it and try again..

Comment: could be some anti-cloning tricks by M$

Comment: I removed the HDD from the laptop ... but it SSD did still not show up in the setup

Comment: load the NVME driver from Samsung during setup: http://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/downloads/software/Samsung_NVMExpress_Driver_rev11.zip (extract the Exe first and point to the folder wit the Inf + sys files)

Comment: I did not find any *.inf *.sys files in the extracted folder (i used 7z to extract) it ...in the setup, I searched for drivers in every folder,
but the setup "did not find any signed drivers"

Comment: BIOS must enable SSD boot as boot path ( assumed done )

Comment: I had to change the sata mode from raid to ahci in the bios... now it works

Comment: @musium ok, post your last comment as answer

Comment: I added the answer. Thanks all of you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the problem by chaning the default "(of my laptop)" BIOS SATA mode
from RAID to AHCI.